# How to plot accuracy of multiple classifiers with multiple datasets

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

I want to plot similar Graph in python. it is basically binary classifiers accuracy report of benign and malicious/attack dataset. there is one benign file and 10 attack files. each attack is combined with the benign file and three classifiers are used to perform classification. the question is how to plot it in python. here is the example image
[classifiers accuracy on with each attack and benign data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeodG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and it is very simple.

1. i stored each model accuracy with all attacks in simple array
2. store name of each attack in array x
3. and accuracy with array y1,y2,y3
4. this blog help me to plot the results
   https://www.w3resource.com/graphics/matplotlib/basic/matplotlib-basic-exercise-5.php